# Conversion from string "" to type Double is not valid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

Im getting this error :

> System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareObject2(Object Left, Object Right, Boolean TextCompare)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareObjectEqual(Object Left, Object Right, Boolean TextCompare)

I have already tried SQL statement and its already working properly .Fields "goals1" and "goals2" are defined as int and "tipp1" and "tipp2" defined varchar(50) . I have tried to convert goals to string didnt work , also tried to convert tipps to int and also it didn't work .And that is the code :

```vb
Private Sub mdlCalculate()
            Try
                Dim _sql As String = "SELECT DISTINCT username FROM fly_tippspiel_tipps"
                Dim _dt As DataTable = cData.getDataTable(_sql, 5, GetCurrentMethod.Name, ControlName)

                If _dt.Rows.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub

                _sql = "DELETE FROM fly_tippspiel_ranking"
                cData.exeNonQuery(_sql, 5, GetCurrentMethod.Name, ControlName)

                For Each _row As DataRow In _dt.Rows
                    _sql = "SELECT Table1.goals1, Table1.goals2, Table1.result1, Table1.tipp1, Table1.tipp2, Table1.result2," & _
                        " ISNULL(Table2.iCount,0) AS iCount" & _
                        " FROM (" & _
                            " SELECT fly_tippspiel_games.id, fly_tippspiel_games.goals1, fly_tippspiel_games.goals2, fly_tippspiel_games.result AS result1," & _
                            " fly_tippspiel_tipps.tipp1, fly_tippspiel_tipps.tipp2, fly_tippspiel_tipps.result AS result2" & _
                            " FROM fly_tippspiel_games" & _
                            " INNER JOIN fly_tippspiel_tipps ON fly_tippspiel_games.id = fly_tippspiel_tipps.games_id" & _
                            " WHERE (fly_tippspiel_tipps.username = '" & _row("username") & "')" & _
                            " AND (NOT (fly_tippspiel_games.goals1 IS NULL))) AS Table1" & _
                        " FULL JOIN" & _
                            " (SELECT fly_tippspiel_games.id, COUNT(fly_tippspiel_games.id) AS iCount" & _
                            " FROM fly_tippspiel_games" & _
                            " INNER JOIN fly_tippspiel_tipps ON fly_tippspiel_games.id = fly_tippspiel_tipps.games_id" & _
                            " WHERE goals1 = tipp1 AND goals2 = tipp2" & _
                            " GROUP BY fly_tippspiel_games.id) AS Table2" & _
                        " ON Table1.id = Table2.id" & _
                        " WHERE NOT Table1.goals1 IS NULL"
                    Dim _dt1 As DataTable = cData.getDataTable(_sql, 5, GetCurrentMethod.Name, ControlName)

                    Dim _sum As Integer = 0
                    For Each _row1 As DataRow In _dt1.Rows
                        If _row1("goals1") = _row1("tipp1") And _row1("goals2") = _row1("tipp2") And _row1("iCount") = "1" Then
                            _sum = _sum + 5     ' alleiniges genaues Ergebnis
                        ElseIf _row1("goals1") = _row1("tipp1") And _row1("goals2") = _row1("tipp2") Then
                            _sum = _sum + 3     ' genaues Ergebnis
                        ElseIf _row1("result1") = _row1("result2") Then
                            _sum = _sum + 1     ' Trend
                        End If
                    Next

                    _sql = "INSERT INTO fly_tippspiel_ranking (username, points) " & _
                           "VALUES ('" & _row("username") & "', " & _sum & ")"
                    cData.exeNonQuery(_sql, 5, GetCurrentMethod.Name, ControlName)
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                cData.exMessage(ex.ToString, GetCurrentMethod.Name, ControlName)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you parametrise your query instead of injecting values and creating a large security vulnerability?

Comment: Imagine what would happen if `_row("username")` contained `'; drop table users --`. There's no need for such code in the first place though. It's far easier and *faster* (at least N times)  to insert the data into a staging table with `INSERT .. SELECT` and then either empty the target table and copy the data, or [partition switching](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/) to swap the target and staging table instantaneously. There's no reason or benefit in copying all the data to the client and back to the server

Comment: `WHERE NOT Table1.goals1 IS NULL` Then obviously you don't want a full join. Usually most people would write that as `WHERE Table1.goals1 IS NOT NULL` - which i personally find much easier to read

Comment: @Zati Anay, which line throws the exception? Besides, it will be better for us to solve the problem if you could provide a small completed code. Such as cData information.